# maven wildfly plugin deploy artifact with classifier

Tags: wildfly, maven-plugin

Maven WildFly plugin not deploying artifact with classifier.

```
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <project.stage>Development</project.stage>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                     <classifier>development</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>development</classifier>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

when running

> $ mvn clean install wildfly:deploy -P development

maven plugin keep looking for artifact without classifier then complaining about not finding it. Same happens with deploy-artifact .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`deploy`](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html) does not have a `classifier` attribute. If you want to deploy your application with a different name you would need to override the `filename` parameter. Something like the following.

```xml
<profile>
    <id>development</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>env</name>
            <value>dev</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <project.stage>Development</project.stage>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                 <classifier>development</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>development</classifier>
                    <filename>${project.build.finalName}-development.war</filename>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

However the [`deploy-artifact`](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-artifact-mojo.html) goal does have a `classifier` attribute. It was not added until `1.1.0.Alpha5` though so you'll need to be using at least that version preferably  `1.1.0.Final`.